# How to do simple authentication with QuickBooks Online without using OAuth?

Tags: java, authorization, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'd like to authenticate myself with my QuickBooks Online account using the Accounting API (Java) so that I can create an invoice.

I've already done this successfully in another app. In that situation, the app had a front-end interface that allowed anyone to login to their account, so I used OAuth for authentication.

In this situation, I simply have some code on my server that will create an invoice in my QuickBooks account, but this code is private, there is no interface associated with it. It is triggered as a result of some business logic that only I control. I have created a new Intuit app with its own keys for this purpose.

Do I still have to go through the OAuth process to authenticate myself? If I do, it seems so unnecessary. For example, to authenticate with OAuth, I have the following:

```
OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new OAuthAuthorizer(
    consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

Context context = new Context(oauth, appToken, ServiceType.QBO, realmID);
DataService service = new DataService(context);
```

The first argument to the `Context` constructor should be an object that implements the `IAuthorizer` interface, of which there are apparently 3: `IAMCookieAuthorizer`, `OAuthAuthorizer` and `TicketAuthorizer`.

The TicketAuthorizer contains a `String` called ticket, but what is this and can I use it? I just want to do simple authentication from a locked down environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't have to go through the OAuth process again. You can use the app token from the other app you mentioned. But since you created a new app at developer.intuit.com you will need to generate a token from that app, which isn't a big deal. You can get a token from the developer.intuit site under "Test connect to app (OAuth)".

Or just go back to using the other apps realm id/company id with its token.

Once you have a token you can programmatically renew it 30 days before expiry, which is 180 days. Therefore, save the token creation date so you can determine the renew window and automatically renew the token in that window.

You can go through the [sample app](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-TimeTracking_Invoicing-DotNet.git) to understand how OAuth works.

Comment: What do you mean by `app token`? From the app dashboard, both the development and production tabs each have their own `App Token`, `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret` values, but its the `access token` and `access token secret` values that I'm missing for the OAuth sign-in. I successfully connected to my QB account using the "Test connect to app (OAuth)" option for my new app (development), but I don't see any access token or access token secret anywhere.

Comment: I've managed to create access token and access secret from the intuit oauth playground, so I'll keep renewing those whenever I can. But I still can't get my requests to work because I don't know what my Realm ID is for my app !! The old app dashboard used to show the realm ID, but I can't find it anywhere in the new dashboard.

Comment: I managed to get it working but only by using my old app, because I came across the realm ID for that app in some logs that I kept. Is there any issues with using oauth tokens for a development version of an app. I mean, does the 180 day expiry and 30 days renewal rule still apply?

Comment: Yes, development tokens are 180 days. The new name for Realm ID is Company ID. Realm Id is still used in the OAuth callback params.

Comment: Is it possible to find out the company ID from the app dashboard, as far as you're aware? Or anywhere else? I examined the headers and params in the HTTP requests/responses during a playground test, and although the RealmID parameter was in there, it had no value. It just seems silly, since the realm/company ID is a completely static value, yet I can't view it anywhere in the dashboard (anymore!).

Comment: No, you're right. I don't see an easy way to obtain the company/realm id.

Comment: It does seem to be removed from the app dashboard, but I eventually found it in my QuickBooks Online account, which does make sense, since it's the same value regardless of whether your using your development or production app. It's under `Your Account` in the settings dropdown menu.

Comment: The token expires after 120 seconds....Is there a way to make this somewhere in the avenue of 120 years?